# How to find number of occurrences of particular character are in uppercase in NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsstring, uppercase

is there any way to find uppercase occurrences of any particular character in `NSString`, for example:

```
NSString *str=@"How many U's are in Uppercase";
```

What i tried is giving all Uppercase characters,

```
int count=0;  
for (i = 0; i < [str length]; i++) {
    BOOL isUppercase = [[NSCharacterSet uppercaseLetterCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[str characterAtIndex:i]];
    if (isUppercase == YES)
       count++;
}
```

OR

```
[[str componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet uppercaseLetterCharacterSet]] count] - 1;
```

But i need uppercase occurrences of any particular character in `NSString`.

Comment: Do you mean the uppercase position in the string or the total uppercase count ?

Comment: What answer do you expect for the example you give? 3 (the number of uppercase letters) or 2 (the number of upper case U)?

Comment: total count, like how many 'U' are in Uppercase@TejaNandamuri

Comment: count should be :2 @Paulw11

Comment: So, as Phillip Mills suggests, just loop through the string comparing each character against your target character and increment the count when you find it.

Comment: is there any other way other than looping, like `NSString` class method@Paulw11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with regular expression:

```
NSString *str = @"How many U's are in Uppercase";
NSString *pattern = @"U";
NSRegularExpression *expression = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:pattern options:0 error:nil];
NSArray *result = [expression matchesInString:str options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, str.length)];
NSLog(@"%ld", result.count); // 2
```

Comment: it will give only uppercase U count or it will include lowercase u into count also?@vadian

Comment: it will only give you the uppercae count as the patter @"U" is in uppercase. @RonakChaniyara

Comment: @RonakChaniyara Only the uppercase letters. But you can provide a *caseinsensitive* option to get both

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use a `NSCharacterSet`, there's `characterSetWithCharactersInString` for building a custom one.  I'm not sure there's any advantage compared to just looping over the string with `==`, though.

Comment: it will be great if you can provide with basic code snippet or logic@Phillip Mills